# Is there a concept of asymptotically independent random variables?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

To prove some results using a standard theorem I need my random variables to be i.i.d.

However, my random variables are discrete uniforms emerging from a rank statistics, i.e. not independent: for two $u_1$,$u_2$ knowing $u_1$ gives me $u_2$.

Yet, my interest is in the asymptotics for ($u_i$) growing infinitely large, and thus these r.v. are becoming more and more independent.

Is there a concept to formalize this idea? Is this standard? Can I have an entry point in the literature?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Could you please elaborate: what do the abbreviations i.i.d. and r.v. mean and which "standard theorem" are you referring to?

Comment: @Hrodelbert These are standard abbreviations in probability theory. The abbreviation i.i.d. means *independent and identically distributed* and r.v. means *random variable* or *random variables*.

Comment: @V.C. I figured as much, but it makes a post accessible to a lot more people if you avoid using such abbreviations.

Comment: @he draws big picture. Respect.

Answer (score 6):

If $(X_n, Y_n)$ are dependent for all finite $n$, but converges in distribution (or "weakly") to some random variable $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ is independent, then we would say that $(X_n, Y_n)$ are asymptotically independent.

Comment: $P(\{X_n\in A\}\cap\{ Y_n \in B\}) \rightarrow   P(X\in A)P(Y \in B)$ as $n\to \infty$ for every Borel sets $A$ and $B$. Is that what you mean?