# Is there a law of the iterated logarithm when the conditions are met asymptotically?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $X_n : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ a sequence of random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
Suppose that:

- $X_n$ converge in distribution to a random variable $X$
- The $X_n$ are asymptotically independent, in any reasonable sense, e.g.:

  - For every $a,b \in \mathbb R$ we have
    $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sup_{m > n} \left|P(X_n \leq a, X_m \leq b) - P(X_n \leq a) P(X_m \leq b)\right| \right) = 0$$
    (see also [Is there a concept of asymptotically independent random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272661))

I.e. the $X_n$ are 'asymptotically' i.i.d.
Does some form of the law of the iterated logarithm remain true?

Specifically, I am interested whether there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k \leq n}X_k}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}} \in [\delta, +\infty] \qquad \text{a.s.}$$

Comment: I don't get asymptotically independent in your context. The answer you linked to had a pair $(X_n,Y_n)$ converging to a pair $(X,Y)$ of independent r.v.'s. Can you be more precise about what you mean?

Comment: @mathworker21 right, edited.

Comment: why did you say $\to 0$ instead of $= 0$?

Comment: That was a typo, thanks.

Comment: I think the answer is no. Consider $X_n$'s defined as follows. $X_n$ is $+1$ with probability $1/2+1/n$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2-1/n$ if $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k < 0$; $X_n$ is $+1$ with probability $1/2-1/n$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2+1/n$ if $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k > 0$; $X_n$ is $+1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$ if $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k = 0$. Then by symmetry, $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$ for each $n$, and then it's clear they have variance $1$ as well.

Comment: They converge in distribution to 50-50 $+1/-1$ and it's clear that bullet point 2 holds. However, I think the $1/n$ bias towards $0$ will prevent the law of the iterated logarithm from holding. If you want, I could think more on how to prove it...

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting! I'll get back to this later this week.

Comment: @mathworker21 It would be interesing to see if any failure of LIL can be attributed to the bias towards $0$ or due to the variance of the partial sums being less than $\sqrt n$.